# How to pass values to another class without using startActivity()

Tags: android

How can I send values to another class without opening it immediately ? 
 It's like I want to save that value first in another class and I will use that value later.

Comment: Please show us the code that you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("YOUKEY", "YOUR VALUE WANT TO SAVE");
editor.apply();  //OR editor.commit() -_-
```

to retrieve it

```
String name = sharedpreferences.getString("YOURKEY",null);
```

Comment: @statosdotcom the apply() save the changes in RAM immediately, and you will get the latest data if you request for it, even if its not saved on the disk yet.

Comment: @AlexKamenkov thanks for the addend, I think, besides of that, my comment remains valid: had the intention of alerting OP about tiny millisecs that can make big trouble. Lazyness is a problem ahah.

Comment: It worked bros ! But is this the proper way to declare a global variable ? Or is there another way ?